# Submitting a form that catches a few errors and saves the other data, how would I get those input values to clear out when the form is resubmitted?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm validating my HTML contact form using PHP. I test the form by submitting the form with no data. then I test the form by submitting partial data. when I submit partial data the correct fields will stay on the form and the other fields will fire err msgs. then I will correctly fill out the form to prevent any errors but when the form is submitted the data is still present on the form instead of being cleared out... so how can i fix this?

I tried using this but its not working:

```php
 function show_data() {
    if (!empty($_POST['firstName'] && isset($_POST['submit']))) {
      if ($lastNameErr || $emailErr || $phoneErr) {
        echo $_POST['firstName'];
      } else {
        echo '';
      }
    }
  }

<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" value="<?php show_data(); ?>">
```

my form:

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
          <label for="firstName">
            First Name <span class="error"><?php echo $firstNameErr; ?></span>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" value="<?php show_data(); ?>">
          </label>

          <label for="lastName">
            Last Name <span class="error"><?php echo $lastNameErr; ?></span>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
          </label>

          <label for="email">
            E-mail <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address">
          </label>

          <label for="phone">
            Phone <span class="error"><?php echo $phoneErr; ?></span>
            <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </label>

          <label for="message">
            Message
            <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Write your message here..."></textarea>
          </label>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">

          <div class="success">
            <?php
              if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if (isset($firstName) && isset($lastName)) {
                  echo '<p>Thank you '.$firstName.' '.$lastName.' for submiting the form';
                } else {
                  echo '';
                }
              }
            ?>
          </div>
        </form>
```

my php code:

```php
function clean_data($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {

  if (empty($_POST['firstName'])) {
    $firstNameErr = '*First name required';
  } else {
    $firstName = clean_data($_POST['firstName']);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
      $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  function show_data() {
    if (!empty($_POST['firstName'] && isset($_POST['submit']))) {
      if ($lastNameErr || $emailErr || $phoneErr) {
        echo $_POST['firstName'];
      } else {
        echo '';
      }
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST['lastName'])) {
    $lastNameErr = '*Last name required';
  } else {
    $lastName = clean_data($_POST['lastName']);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName)) {
      $lastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $emailErr = '*Email required';
  } else {
    $email = clean_data($_POST['email']);
    // check if e-mail address is well formatted
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = 'Not a valid e-mail format';
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phoneErr = '*Phone required';
  } else {
    $phone = clean_data($_POST['phone']);
    // check if the phone number is well formated
    if (!preg_match("/^(\+1|001)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})/",$phone)) {
      $phoneErr = 'Not a valid phone format';
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST['msg'])) {
    $message = '';
  } else {
    $message = clean_data($_POST['msg']);
  }

}
?>
```

I want the form to clear out when the form is submitted, but the input field will remain present even after the form was submitted correctly.

Comment: I think you’re after the PRG pattern (post redirect get).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have value fields filled out using either post values or variables from your validation script because you show the first name example with your function, but none of the other inputs show signs of values derived from PHP. There are different ways to do it depending on where you have placed your business logic. If you have done all your business logic before anything is rendered to the browser, you just redirect back to the the form page after you have determined success. If you need to set a determiner of success for messaging purposes, you can just use a `$_GET` value or `$_SESSION` value:

```
//....your form check code
# Not sure what determines success of your script action, so this function if
# obviously a placeholder, but would return a true or false
$success = whatever_determines_success();
# If the validation is successful and submit is successful
if($success) {
    # Use a redirect header to go back to the form page. The post would be clear at this point.
    header('Location: /whatever_page_the_form_is_on.php?success=1');
    exit;
}
```

Then on the form page:

```
<div class="success">
    <?php if(!empty($_GET['success']))
        echo '<p>Thank you for submiting the form</p>' ?>
</div>
```

There are other ways to do this, but based on what you have thus far, this is probably the most doable in terms of implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back ill find a way to test your code example. I'm currently in my testing phase to make sure the code works before adding the other code. i'm also still in the learning phase as well so all the advice i get really helps